# How to upload a txt file containing json data to php server and save data to mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I m making an android application to back up sms and upload file backed up file containing json data to php server for further saving the data to mysql. I have backed up data in .txt file on sd card but still unable to upload the file to server and then insert data to mysql. Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Why don't use a get oder post request? 
If you want to upload a file to your server the directory must be writeable on your server!

Comment: why you don't pass direct json instead of file?

Comment: I agree with Dhaval, pass direct JSON and have a web service that takes in JSON, decodes it, and inserts it in MySQL. Everything into a txt file would just be more work for you.

Comment: How can i do that? I m new to android and i have been assigned this task to be done. I have got the back up of SMS in txt file containing JSON data but still facing time out exception while try to upload. And how can i directly pass backed up data to php and then save it into the my sql?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask with [Android Client](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) or a Service, but who would want to send you all their sms?

Comment: How? I need an application for user who could archive his own received and sent sms into mysql.